# Exception SqlBulkCopy ColumnsMapping

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I've tried using SqlBulkCopy to migration data between different database and schema.
This is sql command get data from source database:

```
SELECT TOP 2000000 SUBSTRING(HANM002001,1,8) AS HANM002001,
               (HANM002004 +' '+HANM002005) AS HANM002004,
               HANM002007,
               '' AS col4,
               HANM002008,
               (HANM002009+' '+HANM002010) AS HANM002009,
               SUBSTRING(HANM002013,1,13) AS HANM002012,
               SUBSTRING(HANM002013,1,13) AS HANM002013,
               '' AS col9,
               0 AS col10,
               0 AS col11,
               HANM002027,
               HANM002030,
               HANM002033,
               '' AS col15,
               '' AS col16,
               '' AS col17,
               '' AS col18,
               '' AS col19,
               '' AS col20,
               '' AS col21,
               '' AS col22,
               '' AS col23,
               0 AS col24,
               0 AS col25,
               '' AS col26,
               HANM002INS
```

FROM HAN07M002SHIIRE

And here is destination table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mst仕入先](
[仕入先コード] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[仕入先名] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
[仕入先名カナ] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[仕入先略称] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
[郵便番号] [varchar](10) NULL,
[住所] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[電話番号] [varchar](13) NULL,
[ＦＡＸ番号] [varchar](13) NULL,
[担当者コード] [varchar](6) NULL,
[税計算区分] [smallint] NULL,
[端数区分] [smallint] NULL,
[締日] [smallint] NULL,
[入金日] [smallint] NULL,
[入金サイクル] [smallint] NULL,
[銀行コード] [varchar](4) NULL,
[支店コード] [varchar](3) NULL,
[口座番号] [varchar](7) NULL,
[受取人名] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[業者コード] [varchar](6) NULL,
[買掛仕入コード] [varchar](6) NULL,
[買掛経費コード] [varchar](6) NULL,
[現金コード] [varchar](6) NULL,
[表示区分] [smallint] NULL,
[削除フラグ] [smallint] NULL,
[更新者] [varchar](2) NULL,
[更新日] [datetime] NULL,
```

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [仕入先コード] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Here is code mapping:

```
Using sqlCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection.ConnectionString)
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002001", "仕入先コード")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002004", "仕入先名")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002007", "仕入先名カナ")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col4", "仕入先略称")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002008", "郵便番号")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002009", "住所")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002012", "電話番号")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002013", "ＦＡＸ番号")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col9", "担当者コード")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col10", "税計算区分")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col11", "端数区分")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002027", "締日")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002030", "入金日")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002033", "入金サイクル")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col15", "銀行コード")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col16", "支店コード")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col17", "預金種目")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col18", "口座番号")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col19", "受取人名")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col20", "業者コード")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col21", "買掛仕入コード")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col22", "買掛経費コード")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col23", "現金コード")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col24", "表示区分")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col25", "削除フラグ")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("col26", "更新者")
                    sqlCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HANM002INS", "更新日")
                    'sqlCopy.NotifyAfter = importTbl.Rows.Count
                    sqlCopy.DestinationTableName = Constant.ShiiresakiMst
                    sqlCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
                    sqlCopy.WriteToServer(sourceReader)
                End Using
```

But throw exception: The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you don't supply the comlumn mappings? It seems you have the same number of columns so if the ordinal position match you don't need one. My guess is there's something wrong with the destination table name or the encoding which causes it to misread the Chinese letters.

Answer (score 0):

the destination table have only 26 column but you mentioned 27 column in column mapping.